# How to load an ArrayList with instances of an Object I created

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

NOTE: I edited my code to how I think people are trying to tell me but it still doesn't give me my desired output. Now my output is "examples.search.Person@55acc1c2" however many times I enter new first and last names. At least it's making it through the code with out crashing lol

I am learning how to use ArrayLists and need to load an Array list with instances of an Object I created. I know how to do this with an array but for this assignment I need to do it with an ArrayList. Here's an example of what I need to do.

```
// my "main" class
package examples.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import dmit104.Util;

public class MyPeople {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person tempPerson = new Person();
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        char choice = 'y';
        int count = 1;

        // fill my ArrayList
        do {
            people.add(tempPerson);
            // I have a Util class that has a prompt method in it
            firstName = Util.prompt("Enter First Name: ");
            lastName = Util.prompt("Enter Last Name: ");

            tempPerson.setFirstName(firstName);
            tempPerson.setLastName(lastName);

            count++;

            choice = Util.prompt(
                    "Enter another person? [y or n]: ")
                    .toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        } while (choice == 'y');

        // display my list of people
        for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i += 1) {
            System.out.print(people.get(i));
        }

    }

}

// my Person class which I am trying to build from
public class Person {

    // instance variables
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // default constructor
    public Person() {
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I've tried it a number of ways but no matter what my ArrayList doesn't fill up. Like I mentioned I can do it no problem with an array or even if I had a loaded constructor method but I don't. In my actual assignment I am supposed to do it with the set methods.

I have looked everywhere and cannot find the solution for my problem and being friday my instructor isn't in.

Thank you so much in advance

Leo

Comment: Your "default constructor" is not a constructor at all.  The constructor for a class must be named with the same name as the class.  In this case, the constructor must be named Person().  As an aside, unless you have a very strong need for a mutable class, you should always try to instantiate your value objects as instances of an immutable type.  In your case, lastname and firstname should be declared `final` and set to their initial values in the Person() constructor.

Comment: You say you know how to do it for arrays, well, it's not that different, after creating the `ArrayList` `people, you have not objects in it, you have to create them and add them to the list.

Comment: Oh ya scottb, where it says in my class Contact it's supposed to say Person. I forgot to change that when I pasted my code in lol. And I'm actually making a Contact Manager and I need to make it so the user can add and remove contacts and be able to change them (in case someone changes email, phone number etc.)

Comment: Thanks madth3, that's the problem, I don't know how to add them. I can add say just an int or a stringn to an array list but to add new Objects I made myself is where I have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `ArrayList<Person>`, but that alone only defines a list of potential `Person` instances. But so far, each of the list entries is `null`. The `get(i)` returns `null`, and the following `null.setFirstName(..)` causes a NullPointerException.

So you need to create the instances of `Person` that are supposed to go into the list:

```
firstName = Util.prompt("Enter First Name: ");
Person p = new Person(); //create the instance
people.add(p); //add the instance to the list
p.setFirstName("..."); //set any values
```

Comment: Thanks f1sh. So to add multiple instances to my ArrayList I would just add the above code inside a loop? A for loop perhaps?

Comment: I believe it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @leoJaxx yes, use it inside a loop, since you want to create a certain amount of ``Person`` instances and store it in a list. A ``for`` loop is perfect.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh why would it? An ``ArrayList`` has a default size of 10. During the first run, the call ``list.get(0)`` is made, which does not throw an ``IndexOutOfBoundsException`` (since 0 is inside the allowed limits) but returns null.

Comment: @f1sh, I edited it to try yours and another explanations. I put it in the do while loop with my inputs. I left a comment at the beginning of the post. Thanks for all your help I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a `Person` and then `add` it to the `ArrayList`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Person person = new Person();

    person.setFirstName("Foo");
    person.setLastName("Bar");

    people.add(person); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks adashr. So this would work with what I'm trying to do? I just add my inputs between the line "Person person = new Person();" and "person.setFirstName(firstName);" Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 1):

Its crashing because your line `people.get(i).setFirstName(firstName);` is first trying to what is at index i, but you have not set anything yet.

Either first set people[i] to a empty Person, or make a person using firstName and lastName, and add it to people using `people.add(person);`

Answer (score 0):

Now you are storing the Person Object into an ArrayList and printing that Object.
To print the firstname and lastName when you print the Person object, you will have to override toString method.
Add the following code in your Person class

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("[Personn: firstName:%s ,lastName: %s]", firstName,lastName);
}
```

Comment: This was what my class was missing. I just changed the body to only return my variables (firstName + lastName) Thanks. However I chose another answer cuz they gave me the code you see here now. My original code was a mess lol. Thank you tho, I do appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As for the second question you had, you have to override the `toString()` method in the `Person` class. The outputs you are getting, such as `examples.search.Person@55acc1c2` is the default `toString()` method from the `Object` class, which is defined as `class@hashCode`